# How to make a start on a graph traversal algorithm (where edges are one way only)

Tags: algorithm

My assignment asks:

> In a game, a set of nodes is connected via some set of one-way edges.
>   At every node there is an object to pick up. Design an algorithm to find a path that you can follow to collect all objects, if this is possible. To make your task easier, you know that starting from any node, no matter what path you follow, you will never get back to the same node.

My idea here is if I start a node at the beginning, then simply I can follow the path to collect all the nodes. However, I'm stuck on which method should I used to find the starting point. Since the question mentions all the edges are one-way which means this is direct graph. If I starting from a node in the middle, how is that possible to go through all the nodes without going back to the same node.

In addition, could someone explain what exactly one-way edges means, because I'm not sure I understand correctly on this question.

Comment: You can pick nodes one by one and check if you can visit all the nodes (can apply DFS or BFS) from the selected node.

Answer (score 0):

As it is an assignment, here is a hint only - as the graph is acyclic, then the only case where you would be able to visit every node is if there is a path through each node in order.

```
a--->b--->c
 \       /
  \->d--/
```

There is no path than goes through all of a,b,c and d.

```
a--->b----->c
 \    \    /
  \--->d--/
```

there is an order a,b,d,c which goes through all nodes.

So you need to look for a means to order nodes in an acyclic graph in a before/after relationship.